# MVC connecting to server database

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller

I am rebuilding a number of report applications. The application connects to a core system database to display data.

The current report uses a trusted connection string to the core system.

I am new to MVC and wondering how I can make the connection because I do not have (and cannot obtain) the login details for this database. Therefore how do I reference this as nearly all the forums I’ve looked at, use entity framework which prompts a login.

Any help would be great. 
Cheers.

Comment: what makes you think you can't use a trusted connection again?

Comment: Hi. I now have this working. I am using trusted connection. 
Initially I thought you were required to login to the database to access it. 

Thanks.